# How to override this buttons?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8

When I trying to add a new record for a `One2many` tree, I've got a new pop up from(like the image below), I've need validate every value added to the tree, for that, I used onchange methods but they don't work properly...**I would like override the method called when I click over the 'Save & Close' button**, I tried overriding the `write` method, but in this way I don't have so many control over the error message what I want show for every single record added. I'm sure the best way to do what I need is get the name for method called when I clicked over the `Save & Close` method(In other words what method send the values from popup from to the One2many tree?). Please please HELPPP ME!
[image]

**EDIT**: Or how can I call a specific from(wizard) clicking on `Add an item`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call method on Button "Save & Close"

Add Js in module and do like this.

In js file:

```
openerp.module_name = function(instance) {

var QWeb = openerp.web.qweb;
    _t = instance.web._t;

instance.web.FormView.include({
    load_form: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.find('.oe_abstractformpopup-form-save').click(this.on_button_save);
        return self._super(data);
    },
    on_button_save: function() {
        this.dataset.index = null;
        this.do_show();
        console.log('Save & Close button method call...');
    },
});
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Parikshit Vaghasiya, I'm newbie using js function I never used it in Odoo, can you show me how to do that? and how can edit the values passed ?

Comment: in simple way you have to add id or diffrent class to that field in xml and than u got that value in js using js function like $(#'id name').value() and assign or edit value.